# How to increase/decrease the sleep time in clickAndWait command in selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium

```
Command : clickAndWait
Target  : some xpath of the location
```

After executing this command in selenium IDE, it takes huge time to load the data into the page. So in the Log of IDE, I could see as `'Timed out after 30000ms'`.

Is it possible to increase/decrease the value 30000ms ?

```
Command              Target         Value
click              id=ext-gen007    
waitForPageToLoad    60000          wait for one minute
click              id=ext-gen008    
waitForPageToLoad    60000          wait for one minute
click              id=ext-gen009    
waitForPageToLoad    60000          wait for one minute
```

I'm using Selenium IDE 1.8.1 , After editing as above it gives an error as `'Timed out after 60000ms'`

Comment: Ok, then everything works fine.
60000 is still not enough in your case.
You have to increase it even more.

Comment: Double check the "Default time" value in the IDE options.

Answer (score 4):

In Selenium2 / Webdriver you have to use `setTimeout(long milliseconds)`

With Selenium you have to use:

```
<tr>
    <td>setTimeout</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>Wait 60 seconds for the page</td>
</tr>
```

See `setTimeout ( timeout )` in [Selenium Reference](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html)
Also take a look at `waitForPageToLoad ( timeout )`

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>Your XPath</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>Wait one minute</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried with the setTimeout & waitForPageToLoad commands but still getting same error.

Comment: Did you try to split up the click and the waitForPageToLoad ?

`click ( locator )
waitForPageToLoad ( 60000 )`

Comment: And if you use `setTimeout` you have to set it prior to calling open and the "waitFor*" actions.

Comment: Can yoy be bit specifiv about click ( locator ) waitForPageToLoad ( 60000 ) ? can you please set it below
Command : clickwaitForPageToLoad
Target  : locator/xpath
Value   : 60000

is this rite ? if wrong, please modify.

Comment: For setTimeout, i just set it as below 
Command : setTimeout Target  : 100000
clickAndwait command here

Comment: setTimeout only works for the **open** and **waitFor*** Commands.
You have to use **click** and then **waitForPageToLoad**

Comment: I tried as u said,but again same error as Timed out after 'given' time.

Comment: Can you post your Selenium IDE script ?

Comment: I've edited above question. You can find the IDE commands there.