# Selenium network problems

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a problem while using selenium. I have a proof of my web application, but sometimes my network may be very slow or having problems. In that cases I I want to tell Selenium to wait indefinitely until the complete page loads, not matter the time it takes. In other words, I want to configure a infinite timeout.

I tried waitForPageLoad, but it doesn't work for me. For example, I want to left a test running for all night with no timeout but wait until complete page loads.

How can I meet this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is an english language site, however they are working on a spanish language version: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Comment: Can you add your code and some more detail about your problem?

Comment: @apaul34208 me pasa con cualquier codigo, por ejemeplo si yo hago click -> id=Aceptar pero por alguna razon el internet esta muy lento y no ha cargado el boton que no falle por timeout sino que espere infinitamente hasta que aparezca el boton

Comment: No es perfecto, pero intente esto: https://translate.google.com/#auto/es/It%20isn%27t%20perfect%20but%20try%20this%3A

Comment: Use the "edit" link under your question to add information. Utilice el enlace "editar" en virtud de su pregunta para añadir información.

Comment: @apaul34208 no entendi que puedo intentar gracias

Comment: @KarinaSerrano, Vas a tener mucha resistencia con el español en StackOverflow. aPaul está tratando de ayudar, pero tu pregunta parece estar incompleta. Me gustaría hacer más, pero no conozco el producto del que hablan. Puedes añadir información adicional a tu pregunta original (de preferencia en Inglés) para obtener la ayuda que buscas. Si no, añade la información que puedas en español en los comentarios, comenzando el comentario con una llamada a mi usuario y yo con gusto lo traduzco y lo añado a la pregunta original. Un saludo.

Comment: Hi @jachguate i used selenium ide like a complements of mozilla, and i need run my test no matter if network is slow, i need that selenium wait for  the page are ready. I tried with waitForPageToLoad but this needs a time and i don't use time, i want to wait

Comment: @Karina, I have no idea about selenium, but it's usual that you have a defined constant to pass in case you want to infinitely wait for a response. In the case of some libraries I use, it is usually -1 or -2. You must try it and of course read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE has a built in maximum time out of 30 seconds, so it's not possible to set it to longer than that.

There is an addon out there called [implicit wait](http://code.google.com/p/selenium-implicit-wait/), I haven't used it myself so can't really comment on whether it could give you a longer timeout, but it's the most likely solution I'm aware of.

Answer (score -1):

[How to increase/decrease the sleep time in clickAndWait command in selenium IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131836/how-to-increase-decrease-the-sleep-time-in-clickandwait-command-in-selenium-ide)

Might help answer your question about using waitForPageToLoad with a very high number of wait time. Unfortunately there isn't an "infinite" wait setting (like 0 in many applications)